# Window Minimizing after Open a File with GetOpenFileName

Tags: powerbuilder, erp

I'm working on a big project with PowerBuilder, today I stepped on a very weird bug, I have a Window which `buttonclicked()` code is:

```
String  ls_path, ls_nombre, ls_fuente, ls_currentD
int value
long ll_buf
if ib_query then return 1
//Guardar el directorio actual, debido a que la funcion GetFileOpenName lo cambia
ll_buf = 100
ls_currentD = space(ll_buf)
GetCurrentDirectoryA(ll_buf, ls_currentD)   

CHOOSE CASE dwo.name
    CASE "b_2"
        If Object.path_1[row] = '' Or Isnull(Object.path_1[row]) Then
            value = GetFileOpenName("Archivo", ls_fuente, ls_nombre, "*.*", "Archivos(*.*),*.*",ls_currentD,2)          

            Object.documento_path[row] = ls_nombre
            Object.archivo[row] = ls_fuente
        Else        
            ls_fuente = Object.path_1[row]
            ShellExecute(0, "OPEN", ls_fuente, "", "", 0)
        End if      
    CASE "b_3" 
        Choose Case wf_message("Aviso","¿Desea eliminar el archivo adjunto?, el acción será irreversible",4)
            CASE 1
                ls_path = Object.path_1[row]
                If FileDelete ( ls_path ) Then
                    Object.path_1[row] = ""
                    Object.documento_path[row] = ""
                event ue_guardar()
                End IF
            CASE 2
                Return
        End Choose

END CHOOSE
SetCurrentDirectoryA(ls_currentD)
```

When I click on that button, the file selection displays and I can choose my file normally, however, when I press the Accept button from the file dialog the current window minimizes  (On my application we have a menu for window selection so I can recover it just fine) why is this happening? I thought it was the `GetCurrentDirectoryA(ll_buf, ls_currentD)` but that's not the problem, i tried commenting it and still it minimizes the window.

`GetCurrentDirectoryA` is defined like this:

```
FUNCTION ulong GetCurrentDirectoryA (ulong BufferLen, ref String currentdir) Library "Kernel32.dll" ALIAS FOR "GetCurrentDirectoryA;ansi"
```

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: What version of PowerBuilder?

Comment: Version 12.5 Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

There are things in your code that do not fit me. GetFileOpenName does not verify that the result is correct. The ShellExecute function is outside the If where the file that the user chooses is obtained. The ShellExecute function does not apply a Handle (). Please use the function ShellExecute uses the Unicode version:

```
FUNCTION long ShellExecute (uint  ihwnd,string  lpszOp,string
   lpszFile,string  lpszParams, string  lpszDir,int  wShowCmd ) 
   LIBRARY "Shell32.dll" ALIAS FOR "ShellExecuteW"
```

[Example of using ShellExecute](http://picarpiezas.blogspot.com.es/2011/04/como-ejecutar-cualquier-fichero-en.html)

From what I can see in your code I think the problem is in what ShellExecute is called. Please try to make the changes that I mention you to have more control over possible errors in code and to have if this way you locate your problem.

Comment: That's how ShellExecute is declared in my External Functions code. `FUNCTION long ShellExecute(ulong ihwnd,string lpszOp,string lpszFile,string lpszParams, string lpszDir,int wShowCmd ) LIBRARY "shell32.dll" ALIAS FOR "ShellExecuteW"`